# Evitar registros duplicados en C# en modificar

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Tengo una función que no me permite ingresar datos iguales en una misma fila. al momento de ingresar un nuevo producto si funciona no puedo ingresar un producto que ya esta en la base de datos,el problema si yo quiero modificar y solo quiero cambiar ejemplo el precio de venta no se puede porque no se puede guardar con el mismo nombre ALGUNA IDEA ?

***ESTE ES MI BOTON GUARDAR***

```
 private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (modificar)
            {

                Eproductos editar = new Eproductos();
                bool exist = dgvfiltrarproductos.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(row => Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Producto"].Value) == txtnombre.Text);
                bool exist2 = dgvfiltrarproductos.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(row => Convert.ToString(row.Cells["CodSAC"].Value) == txtCodSAC.Text);
                //SI EL VALOR NO EXISTE EN LA BASE DE DATOS LO INGRESA  
                if (!exist == true)
                {

                    if (!exist2 == true)
                    {
                        editar.Codproducto = Convert.ToInt32(txtnombre.Tag.ToString());
                        editar.Producto = txtnombre.Text;
                        editar.CodSac = txtCodSAC.Text;
                        editar.Marca.Codmarca = Convert.ToInt32(txtmarca.Text.ToString());
                        editar.Existencia = Convert.ToDecimal(txtexistencia.Text.ToString());
                        editar.Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(txtprecioventa.Text.ToString());
                        editar.Costo = Convert.ToDecimal(txtpreciocompra.Text.ToString());
                        if (rbtnActvivo.Checked == true)
                        {
                            editar.Activo = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            editar.Activo = false;
                        }

                        Nproductos gestion = new Nproductos();
                        gestion.modificar(editar);
                        MessageBox.Show("Se modifico correctamente", "PRODUCTO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Este CodSAC ya fue ingresado", "REVISE");
                    }
                }
                //SI EL VALOR EXISTE EN LA BASE DE DATOS NO LO INGRESA
                else
                {                     
                    MessageBox.Show("Este producto ya fue ingresado", "REVISE");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Eproductos nuevo = new Eproductos();
                //COMPROBAR SI EL REGISTRO YA EXISTE CON UNA CONSULTA "LINQ" RECORRE TODA LA FILA DEL DATAGRID VIEW Y LA COLUMNA ESPECIFICA  .
                bool exist = dgvfiltrarproductos.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(row => Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Producto"].Value) == txtnombre.Text);
                bool exist2 = dgvfiltrarproductos.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(row => Convert.ToString(row.Cells["CodSAC"].Value) == txtCodSAC.Text);
                //SI EL VALOR NO EXISTE EN LA BASE DE DATOS LO INGRESA                
                if (!exist == true)
                {
                    if (!exist2 == true)
                    {
                        nuevo.Producto = txtnombre.Text;
                        nuevo.Marca.Codmarca = Convert.ToInt32(txtmarca.Text.ToString());
                        nuevo.CodSac = txtCodSAC.Text;
                        nuevo.Existencia = Convert.ToDecimal(txtexistencia.Text.ToString());
                        nuevo.Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(txtprecioventa.Text.ToString());
                        nuevo.Costo = Convert.ToDecimal(txtpreciocompra.Text.ToString());
                        if (rbtnActvivo.Checked == true)
                        {
                            nuevo.Activo = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            nuevo.Activo = false;
                        }
                        Nproductos gestion = new Nproductos();
                        gestion.agregar(nuevo);
                        MessageBox.Show("Se guardo correctamente", "PRODUCTO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listaproducto.Add(nuevo);
                        MessageBox.Show("Este CodSAC ya fue ingresado", "REVISE");
                    }


                }
                //SI EL VALOR EXISTE EN LA BASE DE DATOS NO LO INGRESA
                else
                {
                    listaproducto.Add(nuevo);
                    MessageBox.Show("Este producto ya fue ingresado", "REVISE");
                }              
            }

            ActualizarLista();
            Limpiar();
            Deshabilitar();
            btnGuardar.Enabled = false;
            btnCancelar.Enabled = false;
            btnModificar.Enabled = false;
            btnBuscarmarca.Enabled = false;
            btnNuevo.Enabled = true;
            modificar = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ocaciones he realizado la misma operación pero con usuarios, y se me ha presentado ese problema, utilizando `Java`, la manera en que yo lo solucione, fue la siguiente:

Teniendo seleccionado un usuario a modificar, al darle click al botón de modificar primero hago un `select` a la base de datos, donde obtengo el nombre del usuario seleccionado, si el nombre es igual al que esta en la caja de texto de nombre, lo deja modificarlo, pero si no es pasa a un `else` donde verifica que no choque con ningun otro usuario registrado, si esto es asi lo deja modificarlo sino no.

Aqui te dejo un poco de codigo de lo que te comente antes, para que me entiendas mejor:

```
//Que no se repita, pero que si el que se repite es el mismo, que si lo deje
boolean cumple = false;

String consulta_nombre_usuario = "SELECT Nombre_Usuario"
        + " FROM Usuarios"
        + " WHERE Id_Usuario = " + Id_Usuario;
jClsConexionMetodos CM0 = new jClsConexionMetodos();
String usuario_en_db = CM0.ObtenerValor("Nombre_Usuario", consulta_nombre_usuario);
if (jTxt_NombreUsuario.getText().equals(usuario_en_db))
{
    cumple = true;
} else
{
    //Si no es el mismo, mira si no se repite con ningun otro
    String consulta_usuario_repetido = "SELECT Nombre_Usuario"
            + " FROM Usuarios"
            + " WHERE Nombre_Usuario = '" + jTxt_NombreUsuario.getText() + "'";
    jClsConexionMetodos CM1 = new jClsConexionMetodos();
    String usuario_repetido = CM1.ObtenerValor("Nombre_Usuario", consulta_usuario_repetido);
    if (usuario_repetido.equals(""))
    {
        cumple = true;
    } else
    {
        cumple = false;
    }
}
```

en el caso anterior `Id_Usuario` es la ID del usuario que estoy modificando
`ObtenerValor` es un metodo que funciona de la siguiente manera:

Primer parametro: es la columna de la consulta que deseo que obtenga

Segundo parametro: es la consulta que ejecutara

utilizo un `.equals("")` porque si no encuentra nada el metodo `ObtenerValor`, el esta hecho para que en lugar de `null` retorne un string vacio.

Como agregado puedo decir que la variable `cumple` posterior al final del codigo que vez en esta respuesta cae en un `if`, donde si es `true` sigue el proceso de modificado, si es `false` cae en un `else` donde lanza una alerta donde dice que el nombre ya esta siendo utilizado.

Espero que esto te pueda dar alguna idea de como poder solucionar tu problema, es prácticamente como el que yo te planteo aquí pero aplicado a usuarios, en tu caso seria con productos.

Comment: Me diste una idea creo que ya se como hacerlo Gracias Villatoro